# Using earlier version of python with poetry

Tags: python, pyenv, python-poetry

What is the process for setting up a project and using an earlier version of Python which has not been installed as a system-wide binary?

Ideally, `poetry add <package>` should install to that previous version of python, and `poetry shell` should open up a virtual environment with the correct version.

I have tried:

```sh
mkdir myproj
cd myproj

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
pyenv install 3.8.9
pyenv local 3.8.9

poetry init --no-interaction --python="3.8.9"
poetry env use 3.8.9
poetry add numpy

echo '
import sys
print(sys.version)

import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)
' > main.py

poetry shell
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
python main.py
```

But this gives:

```py
3.8.9 (default, May  1 2021, 22:43:00)
[GCC 10.2.0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

...indicating that the correct version of `python` ran (as expected), but that the package was not installed to python 3.8.9. Indeed:

```sh
λ ls "$(poetry env info --path)/lib"
python3.9

λ grep "version_info" "$(poetry env info --path)/pyvenv.cfg"
version_info = 3.9.4.final.0
```

Comment: Since you tagged `pyenv`, you clearly know a possible answer - what have you tried and what is the problem exactly?

Comment: The added information makes the problem clear (i.e. you expect to have installed `numpy` into the environment, but when running a script, it appears not to be available) - I had a quick look, but see no clear mistake or solution, upvoting your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that everything works correctly for **pyenv 2.x** (released just recently). The new instructions [indicate](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blame/637fd914dc8f66358bdde38efbdeb13e3a64d2b3/README.md#L247) that we now need to update `$PATH` as well with `$HOME/.pyenv/shims`. This is done via:

```sh
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

Poetry now correctly installs `python3.8` to `$(poetry env info --path)/lib` rather than `python3.9` (?!). It is unclear why poetry was doing that in the first place, but I assume it was a pyenv 1.x bug.

---

Full example:

```sh
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

mkdir myproj
cd myproj

pyenv install 3.8.9
pyenv local 3.8.9
poetry init --no-interaction --python="3.8.9"
poetry env use 3.8.9
poetry add numpy

echo '
import sys
print(sys.version)

import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)
' > main.py

poetry run python main.py
```

Output:

```
3.8.9 (default, Sep 14 2021, 18:39:31)
[GCC 11.1.0]
1.21.2
```

Comment: asdf also works.

Answer (score 0):

```
poetry run python main.py
```

You try this command.

---

```
# Initialize pyenv when a new shell spawns
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

# Modify path for Python's poetry dependency management system
export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

Here is a discussion of issues similar to yours：
https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/571

Comment: Adding `eval "$(pyenv init -)"; eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` to `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.zprofile` (which are loaded only for login bash or zsh shells) doesn't seem to fix the fact that poetry is actually managing python 3.9 rather than 3.8. `ls "$(poetry env info --path)/lib"` outputs `python3.9`.

Comment: `$HOME/.poetry/bin` does not exist on my system, so I'm not sure if there's something else I should use there. However, `poetry shell` does activate the virtual environment in `$HOME/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/myproj-izxvOuET-py3.8`.